# Compression of existing file using h5py

Tags: python, compression, hdf5, h5py

I'm currently working on a project regarding compression of HDF5 datasets and recently began using h5py. I followed the basic tutorials and was able to open,create and compress a file while it was being created. However, I've been unsuccessful when it comes to compressing an existing file (which is the aim of my work).

I've tried opening files using 'r+' and then compressing chunked datasets but the file sizes have remained the same.

Any suggestions on what commands to use or am I going about things the wrong way?

Answer (score 5):

HDF group provides a [set of tools](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/) to convert, display, analyze and edit and repack your HDF5 file.

You can compress the existing hdf5 file using the [h5repack](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html) utility. You can also change the chunk size using the same utility.

h5repack can used from command line.

`h5repack file1 file2` //removes the accounted space of file 1 and saves it as file2.

`h5repack -v -l CHUNK=1024 file1 file2` //Applies chunking of 1024 to the file1

`h5repack -v -l CHUNK=1024 GZIP=5 file1 file2` //makes chunks of 1024 and compresses it 
                                                 with GZIP level 5 compression

`h5repack --help` \gets avalable help documentation

[Detailed documentation](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Repack) is also available.

Answer (score 2):

Compression is very easy to use in h5py. Check out the Wiki [HowTo](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/HowTo#Datasets) and [Compression](http://code.google.com/p/h5py/wiki/GuideToCompression) guides.
Basically, it would be something like:

```
ds = myfile.create_dataset('ds', shape, dtype, compression='lzf')
```

There is also some issues with how you pick chunk sizes to optimize file size/access, see the Compression guide I linked to.

I do not remember which compression, if any, is on by default.

Comment: Yes I've tried exactly that, however it seems to only work for me while creating a new file eg. I can create a new file with chunk size (100,100) which has gzip/szip/lzf compression enabled. When I load an existing file, the only way the compression seems to actually function is if the contents of the original file are overwritten and a new one is created (with the same name of the original).

When I load a file, create a chunked dataset, enable compression and then close the file, there seems to be no effect or change at all. I get the feeling I'm missing a step, not sure what it is though.

Comment: @kromegaman compression and chunk size are guidelines of how the file is written to disk. I don't think that is something you can change for an existing file, as it is already written. I think the only way to change compression/chunks is to write a new file with those settings.

Comment: Yes the more I use it the more it seems to be that way. I think I'll have to create a new file and dataset, copy the data from the existing file into the new one and then compress the new file as I create it. Nonetheless, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @kromegaman Further to what Bitwise said, compression and chunk size, along with some other properties, are set when you create a _dataset_, and can not be changed afterwards. Different datasets can use different compression algorithms or chunk sizes. Also, there is no compression by default.