# How do I add values in parallel to an existing HDF5 file with 3 groups and 12 datasets in each group using h5py?

Tags: python, mpi, hdf5, h5py, mpi4py

I have installed the libraries using this [link](https://drtiresome.com/2016/08/23/build-and-install-mpi-parallel-hdf5-and-h5py-from-source-on-linux/). I have already created an `HDF5` file called `test.h5` using `mpiexec -n 1 python3 test.py`. `test.py` is as below and I'm not sure if it is necessary to use `mpi4py` here, please let me know.

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import h5py

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=comm)

f.create_group('t1')
f.create_group('t2')
f.create_group('t3')

for i in range(12):
    f['t1'].create_dataset('test{0}'.format(i), (1,), dtype='f', compression='gzip')
    f['t2'].create_dataset('test{0}'.format(i), (1,), dtype='i', compression='gzip')
    f['t3'].create_dataset('test{0}'.format(i), (1,), dtype='i', compression='gzip')

f.close()
```

Now, I would like to write a `test1.py` file that will:

1. Open `test.h5` and get all the unique keys (they are the same for all three groups).
2. Make chunks of those keys, like `chunks = [['test0','test1','test2'],['test3','test4','test5'],['test6','test7','test8'],['test9','test10','test11']]`. I don't care about the the order or groupings of these chunks but I would like one chunk per process.
3. For each chunk assign a process to store a value for every key in that chunk in every group. In other words I would like to run this function in parallel:

```
def write_h5(f, rank, chunks):
    for key in chunks[rank]:
        f['t1'][key][:] += 0.5
        f['t2'][key][:] += 1
        f['t3'][key][:] += 1
```

How do I do this? Can you please explain in detail? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test1.py should contain:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import h5py

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

def chunk_seq(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0
    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg
    return out

def write_h5(f, chunk):
    for key in chunk:
        f['t1'][key][:] += 0.5
        f['t2'][key][:] += 1
        f['t3'][key][:] += 1

f = h5py.File('test.h5', 'a', driver='mpio', comm=comm)
chunks = chunk_seq(list(f['t1'].keys()), size)

write_h5(f, chunks[rank])

f.close()
```

Run it using: `mpiexec -n 4 python3 test1.py`. The problem is that this will only work if you don't set `compression='gzip'` while creating the datasets. For reference check the question [Does HDF5 support compression with parallel HDF5 ? If not, why ?](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/hdf5-quest.html#p5comp) but I'm not sure if this holds true for the latest version. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903867/compression-of-existing-file-using-h5py) it seems like you'll have to read each dataset serially and create a corresponding dataset in a new `HDF5` file with compression.